# SlidingMenu Build Error

Tags: android, slidingmenu, build-error

I have imported the jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu to my workspace using git but it shows lot of error I tried to clean the project it shows the following error

```
Errors occurred during the build.Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'com.menorking.android'.java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I'm really frusted with this error I tried to delete all the projects on workspace still it's not working, and Also tried to import it from a zip showing the same error

Comment: Paste the code and the LogCat too.

Comment: Actually I did'nt create any project yet. I simply just imported the SlidingMenu to the workspace through git. Suddenly It shows the above error and the SlidingMapActivity.java file shows lot of errors @g00dy

Comment: Did you compare the two projects` Manifests to see if there isn't any discrepancies?

Comment: Try to clean the project and see. Let me know what happens. Also let me know if the library project on your workspace is having any errors or is the build error free. You need to import from an error free build.

Comment: I am having the same problem! You haven't found a solution yet have you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I imported using `git` in `eclipse` it tried to import the master branch, but that had a sub-folder of the same name which was not a project itself, but contained projects inside of it. So when I had it all imported, it was an Android Project that was really 3 projects smushed together into the same directory, so everything was messed up in the build.

So instead I downloaded the zip, and extracted the contents and went to `File`>> `Import`>> `Android/Exisiting Android Code Into Workspace`. I selected the folder at */`SlidingMenu-master/SlidingMenu-master`. This inner folder of the same name then had 3 projects: 
`library`, `com.menorking.Android`, and `ExampleListActivity`.

Without selecting the sub folder, I just got 1 messed up project of the name `com.menorking.Android`.

The GitHub page for `SlidingMenu` has assurances that git is the way to go for importing the project, but I am not git savvy enough to know how to do that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

File->New->Other->Android Project from Existing Code
then select the Root Directory for exemple(C:\Users\user\Downloads\SlidingMenu-master\SlidingMenu-master\library) select the project to Import  and check the checkbox "**copy projects into workspace**" and Finsh.